# Passing an Ordinal Parameter

Tags: delphi, parameters, types, delphi-2007, ordinal

Is it possible to write a method which takes any ordinal type as a parameter? The same way Inc() or High() do?

I'm using Delphi 2007

Comment: What are you trying to do? Aren't plain overloaded methods a solution?

Comment: with overloaded methods I'd need to write a new method for every enumeration I wanted to use.

Comment: @JamesB, So?  Your question ask if it's possible to write a function that take any ordinal. Overloading is a valid way to do it. David's answer is the closest you can get to Inc() or High().  You didn't say anywhere in your question what your function would be doing, or what kind of ordinal it would receive in parameter.  And even though enumeration are "technically" ordinal, they would be more properly described as an "array of bits" (Both in concept and implementation). Also, the size of an enumeration is variable, (8 to 256 bits), which makes it a lot harder to write a generic method.

Comment: @Ken Bourassa, a `set of enumeration` is an array of bits, an enumeration is just a list of named constants, with ascending values (unless you go out of your way to manually assign values). They're very much enumerations.

Comment: @Cosmin, My bad... I guess I should stop answering questions @ 3:00 AM. lol.

Comment: There must be a better way to beat your coding problem. This seems like "Pascal: how to shoot yourself in the foot"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd need to use an [untyped parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Untyped_Parameters):

```
procedure Foo(const ordinal);
```

or

```
procedure Foo(var ordinal);
```

Of course, you are somewhat limited in what you could do inside such a routine because you have abandoned the type system.

Comment: Is the size of the ordinal guaranteed to be 4 bytes?

Comment: Well, now you can pass *anything* to these procedures, not only ordinals. So this is not how `inc` etc. works. (Indeed, code insight says that the argument of `inc` is `var X: ordinal`. But this behaviour you can't get in a proc/func of your own, I think.)

Comment: @James I answered your question. Now you are changing your question in the comments. What is you actual problem?

Comment: @David, sorry I've removed that comment.

Comment: Untyped parameters are a really low level bit of hackery, and in this case, unless you only really need to examine the bytes you are being passed and do something with those bytes, this is not a good general solution.    Perhaps if you need to write a general function that can write the binary representation of any type, to disk, this could be useful. But beware, many people have made themselves a mess, using untyped parameters.  If you know C, you should be able to see how in the end, this is a lot like passing a "void *" pointer.

Comment: @Warren I agree. Question specifically wanted to bypass type system.

Comment: +1, You can also pass the number of bytes, like procedure Foo(var AOrdinal; Size: Integer); and call it Foo(MyOrdinal, SizeOf(MyOrdinal)).  That way your routine can handle ordinals of different sizes.  Kind of hack, if you want... but very fast and convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Found a possible way, might not be what you expect, but hey, I found a way! Use `Variants`. The problem with passing typeless parameters to a procedure is that you get a plain pointer, no type information, so you can't do anything useful with it. Bytes are 1 byte, enums of up to 256 elements are 1 byte byte, enums of up to 2^16 elements are 2 bytes, integers are 4 bytes (unless they're 8). But there is one type that allows anything to be passed and cares enough type information to make things work: the `Variant`. I *intentionally* wrote the following example in Delphi 7, to make sure I don't accidentally use any Delphi 2010 or Delphi XE goodness.

*Edit*: Updated the code sample to handle *any* type that's considered Ordinal by the `Variants.VarTypeIsOrdinal`. That includes all integer types + Boolean. Apparently Enum is seen as Byte, so it swallows that too.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  ExceptionLog,
  SysUtils, Variants;

type TSomeEnum = (e0, e1, e2, e3, e4);

procedure DoSomethingWithEnum(V: Variant);
var i: Integer;
    b: Byte;
    lw: LongWord; // Cardinal!
    i64: Integer;
begin
  case VarType(V) of
    varInt64:
      begin
        i64 := V;
        WriteLn(i64);
      end;
    varSmallint, varInteger, varShortInt:
      begin
        i := V;
        WriteLn(i);
      end;
    varByte:
      begin
        b := V;
        WriteLn(b);
      end;
    varWord, varLongWord:
      begin
        lw := V;
        WriteLn(lw);
      end;
    varBoolean:
      begin
        if V then WriteLn('True') else WriteLn('False');
      end;
    else WriteLn('NOT a variant type (type = #' + IntToStr(Ord(VarType(V))));
  end;
end;

var i: Integer;
    b: Byte;
    c: Cardinal;
    enum: TSomeEnum;
    w: Word;
    si: Shortint;

begin
  i := 1;
  b := 2;
  c := 3;
  enum := e4;
  w := 5;
  si := -6;

  DoSomethingWithEnum(i);
  DoSomethingWithEnum(b);
  DoSomethingWithEnum(c);
  DoSomethingWithEnum(enum);
  DoSomethingWithEnum(True);
  DoSomethingWithEnum(w);
  DoSomethingWithEnum(si);

  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: @Warren, Variants might not be as fast as we'd like them to be, but they're not that slow either.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why doing this is difficult is that Inc(x), Dec(x) and others like Pred(x) and Succ(x) are actually, generated by the compiler, and are, if you like, merely Function style syntax sugar over an inherent compiler operation.

You can, as some people suggest, do some of this with overloading, some of it with clever use of generics, and some of it with variants. But nothing will be as convenient for emulating these functions, or exactly the same functionally.

The compiler implements Inc() for example, for all ordered types, including Enums, Integers, and subranges on those types (a now rather obscure feature of classic "Wirth" Pascal is that all types can have subranges defined on those types).

If you actually told us more about what you were doing, it might be possible to get closer. But the general answer is, No, there isn't even source code for Inc, and Dec, because these are compiler primitives.  If there was RTL source code to the function Inc, you could go look at it, and adapt it.

inc(x) could be defined  as x := Succ(x), but then, how do you define Succ(x)?  As x := Inc(x)?  You see.  At some point, compiler "magic" takes over.